# criteria query on entities not having joins

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Is there any way to write criteria query on entities not having explicit joins ? By explicit join I mean that 2 tables in database have no foreign key relationship but  some columns need to be fetched from both the tables so joins are required in query. I know that queries having join can be written with 'in' clause and criteria queries can be written with "In" criteria. I have written HQL for this case but please tell me how to write criteria query for this case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the **cross join** would be solution, but that is possible ONLY with **HQL**. Check doc *(small cite)*:

#### [16.2. The from clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-from)

> Multiple classes can appear, resulting in a cartesian product or "cross" join.

```
from Formula, Parameter

from Formula as form, Parameter as param
```

And, also, we can filter on any of these two Entities inside of the WHERE clause, to narrow the cartesian product...

Comment: thanks for the answer but I think this is for HQl not for criteria API's.

Comment: Wow, sorry, I was not explicit. This is the ONLY way how to achieve this. ONLY with HQL. No way with Criteria API. Sorry... ;) But still we have solution (even if this is HQL)

Comment: kindly update your answer with the statement you have written in comments.